# Make folder in .special folder hidden C#

Tags: c#, directory

i know im doing something small wrong im just braindead right now. The path is the problem, i tried to use path.combine and also put system.IO in front of it but nothing worked.

```
string path = (Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData + @"\MSPhone").ToString();
        File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Comment: what path do you end up with / what path do you want?

Comment: the path i want = \AppData\Roaming\MSPhone
the path im getting = ApplicationData\MSPhone
i think i might have the wrong special folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `Environment.GetFolderPath` along with your `SpecialFolder`.  `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` is just an `enum` value, not representative of the path without acting on it:

```
Path.Combine(
       Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
       "MSPhone");
```

this gives me `"C:\Users\jonesopolis\AppData\Roaming\MSPhone"`

and of course, always use `Path.Combine` rather than building the path yourself.